# Multiple JWT's match hashed JWT

Tags: hash, jwt, bcrypt, bcryptjs

I'm using bcryptjs to hash a user's refresh_token before storing it in my database.

It seems that the following always evaluates to true when comparing a hashed string with a JWT, I've also gotten the same behavior on https://bcrypt-generator.com/

for example the hash `$2a$10$z4rwnyg.cVtP2SHt3lYj7.aGeAzonmmzbxqCzi2UW3SQj6famGaqW` is a match with the following two JWTs

`eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VySWQiOiI2NTZlODdkNi1jMmVkLTRmN2ItOTU2Zi00NDFhMWU1NjA2MmQiLCJpYXQiOjE2Mzk1OTg2MDIsImV4cCI6MTY0MjE5MDYwMn0.aJlzFHhBMGO4J7vlOudqOrOFnL1P-yEGrREgdaCXlxU`

`eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VySWQiOiI2NTZlODdkNi1jMmVkLTRmN2ItOTU2Zi00NDFhMWU1NjA2MmQiLCJpYXQiOjE2Mzk2MDY4ODgsImV4cCI6MTY0MjE5ODg4OH0.vo4HKLXuQbT0Yb0j21M4xl-rakxyE5wINjuGdkPuSJY`

You can verify these on the site as well that they both result in a 'match'

1. Go to https://bcrypt-generator.com/ and open your browser console.
2. Enter these lines into the console:

   ```
   > var jwt1 = "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VySWQiOiI2NTZlODdkNi1jMmVkLTRmN2ItOTU2Zi00NDFhMWU1NjA2MmQiLCJpYXQiOjE2Mzk1OTg2MDIsImV4cCI6MTY0MjE5MDYwMn0.aJlzFHhBMGO4J7vlOudqOrOFnL1P-yEGrREgdaCXlxU"
   < undefined

   > var jwt2 = "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VySWQiOiI2NTZlODdkNi1jMmVkLTRmN2ItOTU2Zi00NDFhMWU1NjA2MmQiLCJpYXQiOjE2Mzk2MDY4ODgsImV4cCI6MTY0MjE5ODg4OH0.vo4HKLXuQbT0Yb0j21M4xl-rakxyE5wINjuGdkPuSJY"
   < undefined

   > var h = "$2a$10$z4rwnyg.cVtP2SHt3lYj7.aGeAzonmmzbxqCzi2UW3SQj6famGaqW"
   < undefined
   ```
3. Then enter these lines into the console, observe how they return `true`:

   ```
   > bcrypt.compareSync(jwt1, h)
   < true
   > bcrypt.compareSync(jwt2, h)
   < true
   ```

---

This is my own JS code that also reproduces the hash match:

```
// Login Logic

const refresh_token: string = jwt.sign({ userId }, authSecrets.refresh_secret, { expiresIn: '30d' });

const hash_refresh = bcrypt.hashSync(refresh_token);

await UserModel.update({
    id: user.id,
    refresh_token: hash_refresh,
});
```

```
// Refresh logic
// 'value' is the payload after using joi to validate it 

const claims: any = jwt.verify(value.refresh_token, authSecrets.refresh_secret);

user = await UserModel.get(claims.userId);

if (!bcrypt.compareSync(value.refresh_token, user.refresh_token)) {
    // This never happens with any JWT!
    return response(401, 'Refresh Token is incorrect');
}
```

Why is this happening? the strings are clearly different (although not by a lot).

Comment: "that the following always evaluates to true" - but you haven't actually posted any JS expressions that "evaluates to true" - instead you've posted multi-statement JS examples that don't _evaluate_ to anything because a statement isn't an expression. And we need example values for `userId` and other parameters.

Comment: `bcrypt.compareSync(value.refresh_token, user.refresh_token)` this is the expression that evaluates to true, you'll find it within the 'if' statement

for bcrypt-generator.com you can use the hash I posted above and use either of the JWT strings above and they will both evaluate to true. userId is an UUID and should not effect the problem here

Comment: There are hundreds of `if` statements on bcrypt-generator.com from all the scripts loaded onto it. Please be more specific. Just give me some JS I can literally copy-and-paste into my browser console.

Comment: Okay, I am now able to reproduce the issue you're describing after fiddling around on bcrypt-generator.com. I agree, this is weird.

Comment: BTW, [the `bcryptjs` library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcryptjs) hasn't been updated in **5 years**, have you considered [the `bcrypt` package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt) instead? That's still actively developed.

Comment: Sorry I may have been unclear in my original question, the code snippet was from my own source code, not bcrypt-generator.com, but I was able to reproduce it through the site as well, I thought it might be easier to reproduce it on the site than try to replicate my source code locally (installing packages, etc)

Comment: Ah, here we go: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/39849/does-bcrypt-have-a-maximum-password-length

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The hash collisions are because bcrypt [only hashes the first 72 bytes of input](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/39849/does-bcrypt-have-a-maximum-password-length) (in most implementations).

This is documented in the README for both the `bcryptjs` and `bcrypt` npm packages:

[bcryptjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcryptjs):

> The maximum input length is 72 bytes (note that UTF8 encoded characters use up to 4 bytes) and the length of generated hashes is 60 characters.

[bcrypt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt):

> Per bcrypt implementation, only the first 72 bytes of a string are used. Any extra bytes are ignored when matching passwords. Note that this is not the first 72 characters. It is possible for a string to contain less than 72 characters, while taking up more than 72 bytes (e.g. a UTF-8 encoded string containing emojis).

(That's an objectively terrible design considering this is for user-security... The bcryptjs library really should always throw an exception if the input exceeds 72 bytes IMO)

I note that bcrypt is design for human-supplied (i.e. non-random) passwords, not as a general-purpose message-digest algorithm. Given you don't need to add a salt to randomly-generated passwords (like your `refresh_token` value) you probably should use something like a SHA-2 family algorithm (e.g. SHA-256, but not SHA-1) for this.

Comment: I can't believe I missed this, thanks so much!